# Call jar.exe,error C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\jar.exe is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, jar

I want to package some classes into one file.
So I try to run command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\jar.exe
```

But the error is weird. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\jar.exe is not a valid Win32 application.`

What should I do now? Do I need to install any other tool?

Comment: Did you extract the correct JDK version (i.e. 64-bit instead of 32-bit)? Maybe try re-extracting/installing...could be a corrupt file.

Comment: Do you have a 64 or a 32-bit operating system?

Comment: @hall.stephenk,thank you.I reinstall the 64bit version jdk.That works.

Comment: @roast_soul: glad I could help...go ahead and submit your own answer and mark it as the solution. That will close out this post and let others know what steps you took to fix the problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstall the 64bit version jdk, and it works